# VirtualBox won't expand guest system's window

Tags: virtualbox, ubuntu-10.10

I have a problem with VirtualBox - my guest system is ubuntu 10.10 and after update, some of the VirtualBox's Guest additions functions stopped working. For example - before the update whole window of VB was occupied by guest's desktop, and now it's only like 70%. I had the same problem on my other computer with same guest OS, and it's update.

Comment: Not clear what was updated? The Guest OS? If so, you probably have to re-install the guest additions.

Comment: Yes, the guest OS was updated and re-installing guest additions didn't help..

Comment: Well, actually the second reboot helped, strange...

Comment: Actually I'm experiencing an issue with windows resizing each time I update the guest OS. I just reinstall the Guest Additions. Usually that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you can pick the wrong script file for guest additions. You must use the Linux ones and NOT the .sh Guest Additions [hope my tutorial helps you](http://thejarbar.org/views/tutorials/windows/Virtualbox-Setup.xhtml)

Answer (score 0):

If you run "apt-get dist-upgrade" then it might update the kernel.  This can mess with the guest additions.  You will have to re-install guest additions after doing the update.  Then everything should be fine.